# Are there other quota limit for email in GAE?

Tags: email, google-app-engine, quota

My app receive an email from an address, parse it, and forward the result to a two different addresses as attachment. The attachment is less then 10K and message less then 1k (plain text). No queues.
I'm debugging, so I can send a email for two recipients every 5 minutes or more (I checked the log).

Quota show me: all the resources at 0% exept for email recipients, these are 11% of the daily quota.

But in each day I'm debugging it, after some runs (today ~33) I run overquota, and I have to wait until the day after. All messages are forwarded to the same address: is there some other quota in addition to the limits per minute and per day?

Answer (score 2):

There is a 10 email limit for Free Quota and 100 if you have billing enabled. But it is not recommended to use the email sending from app engine anymore and they recommend using an email service for that. Sendgrid gives you 12k email per month for free.

If you are using this and sending it to yourself and that email is the project owner/admin. You can use send_email_to_admins() and it gives you 5000 emails per day.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas

Comment: I misinterpreted the limit of 10 recipients. I had understood as different recipients.
However, my console show me that the limit is 100 (many more the ones I need) but it seems that real limit is 10.
I think I have billing enabled, but to be sure, where I have to check?

Comment: When you open the menu you can check the billing tab or in appengine settings check the settings tab daily spending limit. I checked my mail limit, it does show the old quota when I created the app.

Comment: I see my billing account, and as limit I see 100 recipients as expected. But as soon as I send email to 10 recipients, I go overquota!

Comment: I'm on the free tier so far but I also noted that even if I send three emails to the same email address that still counts as 3 recipients, very confusing. It must be a bug.